# Can not get value for top node by observing database reference in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the list of branches from Firebase database(in this example [branch1,branch2]) in Swift language,
when I observe the top node ("branches") it returns nothing and even the first print function is not being called, but if I observe one of the branches like branch1 it works fine.
now how can I retrieve the list of branches ([branch1,branch2])

```
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("branches").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        print("+++++++++++++++++ ")

        print("++++++++++++\(snapshot.hasChildren())")
        for child in snapshot.children{

            let branch = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
            let branchName = branch.key as! String
            print("\(branchName)") 
       }

   }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6JIM.jpg)

```
{  "Users" : {
"6dICrkbVVJWzVZ00Vq4y9Fm2Qcg2" : {
  "branches" : {
    "branch1" : true
  },
  "isAdmin" : true
},
"M0C1XUyboPg5zbgQi24nh3SlJri1" : {
  "branches" : {
    "branch2" : true
  }
}  },"branches" : {
"branch1" : {
  "address" : "NDG",
  "campaigns" : {
    "valentine's day" : true
  },
  "manager" : "y",
  "rate" : {
    "average" : 0,
    "bad" : 0,
    "good" : 0
  },
  "users" : {
    "6dICrkbVVJWzVZ00Vq4y9Fm2Qcg2" : true,
    "M0C1XUyboPg5zbgQi24nh3SlJri1" : {
      "isAdmin" : true
    }
  }
},
"branch2" : {
  "address" : "downtown montreal",
  "manager" : "x",
  "rate" : {
    "average" : 0,
    "bad" : 0,
    "good" : 0
  },
  "users" : {
    "M0C1XUyboPg5zbgQi24nh3SlJri1" : true,
    "Z6b5WalkNWZLMVdwGPHi3vSvSRU2" : {
      "isAdmin" : true
    }
  }
}  },  "campaigns" : {
"valentine's day" : {
  "branches" : {
    "branch1" : true
  }
}  }}
```

and the working code for getting branch1 is :

```
   ref.child("branches").child("branch1").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

      let address = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "address").value 
      print("\(address)")
   }
```

and it will print the right result (NDG)

security rules :

```
{  "rules": {
"Users":{
  "$uid":{
    ".read":"auth.uid == $uid || root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val()==true",
    ".write":"auth.uid == $uid || root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val()==true"


  }

},  "branches":{
"$branchId":{
".read" : "auth.uid == true || root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val()==true || root.child('branches').child($branchId).child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write" :  "auth.uid == true || root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val()==true || root.child('branches').child($branchId).child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val()==true"

}}}}
```

Comment: Can you add the code to your question that works where you are observing branch1? Also, it's best practice to post your firebase structure as text, not an image or link. That way it's searchable and we don't have to retype it when answering and most importantly, if who ever is hosting the image changes, it breaks the question. So stick with including it as text.

Comment: thank you @Jay , I will do so

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the security rules? It seems that `/branches` is **not** readable, while `/branches/$branchID` is.

Comment: @vzsg  I have added the rules

Comment: I have changed the rule and it worked properly , I am wondering why it is not working since I am using admin account and admin should be able to do so

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @vzsg I found out that the problem was with the permission and rules. so I changed the rules and I get the result easily

```
{  "rules": {
      "Users":{
        "$uid":{
    ".read":"auth.uid == $uid ||       root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val()==true",
    ".write":"auth.uid == $uid || root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val()==true"


  }

},  "branches":{
        ".read": " root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val()==true" ,
        ".write" :  "root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val()==true ",

"$branchId":{
   ".read": " root.child('branches').child($branchId).child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()",
   ".write" :  "root.child('branches').child($branchId).child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val()==true"

}}  }}
```